# How to hide bootstrap slider and all image should be display vertically on mobile device?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Is there any way to hide bootstrap slider  and all images in slider should be displayed in vertically on the mobile device?
I have 5 images in the slider and I have to display all image vertically on a mobile device.I tried in media query below code but it's not working.Please help me in this.

```
#myCarousel.carousel-inner > .item 
   {
    display: block !important;
   }
```

Comment: add your html code.

Comment: Are your images in the slider? - "Hiding the bootstrap slider" will also hide the images.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Pratik, I am using Bootstrap slider.

Comment: Yes Mr.Birksy89, All images are in slider. Is there any way to display only images vertically?

Comment: I'm curious to know if the reason you wish to do this is purely for aesthetics, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bootstrap Carousel on mobile devices

1. The carousel becomes paused.
2. The images display vertically.
3. Each caption is placed under its image. (You can remove the code for the `.carousel-caption` class if you don't need this feature.)

I've created this solution for a similar issue. Please check is it what you want to achieve?

For Bootstrap 4: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/ExxKXZb
For Bootstrap 3: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/rLwAWp

```js
var isCarouselPaused = false;

$( window ).on( 'load resize', function() {
  if ( document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 767 ) {
    if ( !isCarouselPaused ) {
      $( '#myCarousel' ).carousel('pause');
      isCarouselPaused = true;
    }
  } else {
      if ( isCarouselPaused ) {
      $( '#myCarousel' ).carousel('cycle');
      isCarouselPaused = false;
    }
};
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel .item {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  .carousel-control, 
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
  
  /* Place captions under their slides */
  .carousel-caption {
    color: black;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  
  /* Decorations */  
  .carousel-caption h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
}

/* Make the images wide and responsive. */
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Decorations */  
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    
      <h1>Bootstrap Carousel on mobile devices</h1>
      
      <p>On the narrow screen the carousel is paused and the items display vertically.</p>
      
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>First Header</h3>
              <p>Text text text text text text text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Second Header</h3>
              <p>Text text text text text text text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Third Header</h3>
              <p>Text text text text text text text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
      </div>
      
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome Gleb, It's working for me.Great thank you very much.

Comment: @Hybreeder I've improved my solution. Now captions are placed under their images on the narrow scrren. (You can remove the code for the .carousel-caption class if you don't need this feature.)

Answer (score 1):

Write proper media query like below.

```css
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .carousel-inner>.item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```